# Android Service and unregisterReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I use one Service that send same information to an activity with BrodcastReceiver. This service start when the activity go to onPause and into onPause I register also the Receiver. When the activity Resume I stop the service and unregister the Recevier. The problem is that when the activity go to onPause I read into application's log this message

> 03-25 11:26:50.173: E/ActivityThread(19603): Activity
>   it.android.dev.project.myactivity has leaked IntentReceiver
>   it.android.dev.project$receiver@419ff300 that was originally
>   registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

But in onPause I don't must unregister the receiver because I use it for communicate with the activity...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot communicate with an activity that is in the background this way. Moreover, it is useless to communicate with an activity this way, since the activity is not in the foreground and therefore the user cannot see any changes, anyway.

In `onResume()` of this activity, kick off whatever work you need to do to update it based on things that happened in the background while the activity was not in the foreground.